# ActiveAdmin: Displaying form as an IFRAME within another form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, activeadmin

I am developing an application with a Gallery model and an Images model, where each gallery has_and_belong_to_many images.

I'm currently developing the form for creating/editing a gallery. From this form, I would like users to be able to both add existing images and upload new images to the gallery. After much mucking about, I was able to use the Rails "nested model forms" functionality to achieve this, but the end result was unsatisfactory from a UI perspective.

I've realized that what I really need is an IFRAME in my gallery form that contains an image form. How can I include the image form as an IFRAME without all the surrounding markup that is normally rendered along with the form (e.g., the header, the title bar, and the footer)? Note in the code below that I am already using ":layout => false" when I call "render" in my "new_iframe" controller method.

Here is my Image resource file:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Image do

  controller.authorize_resource

  scope_to :current_admin_user

  collection_action :new_iframe, :method => :get do
    @image = Image.new    
    render :action => :new, :layout => false
  end

  controller do
    ...
  end

  index do
    column :title do |image|
      link_to image.title, edit_admin_image_path(image)
    end
    column :image do |image|
      image_tag(image.thumb_path, :alt => "")
    end
    column :created_at
    column :updated_at
    default_actions
  end

  form :html => { :enctype => "multipart/form-data" } do |a|
    a.inputs "Image", :multipart => true do
      a.input :title
      a.input :asset, :as => :file
    end    
    a.buttons
  end

end
```

Comment: I would be *very* surprised if the form fields in the embedded IFRAME document were included in the parameters when the form was submitted. Have you tested that this works with a very simple HTML form field, first?

Comment: Jon, the idea is that the IFRAME has its own form with its own submit button, allowing it to be submitted independently of the surrounding form. You are correct that the inner form fields won't be submitted along with the surrounding form.

Answer (score 0):

in the model file (where media is your gallery model)

```
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :media, 
:reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:image].blank? }, 
:allow_destroy => true
```

in active admin

```
    f.inputs "Media" do
  f.has_many :media do |j|
    j.inputs "media" do
      if !j.object.nil?
        j.input :_destroy, :as => :boolean, :label => "Destroy?"
      end
      j.input :image, :hint => f.template.image_tag(j.object.image.thumb.url(), :width => '100')

    end
  end
end
```